# jQuery check url string for first hash and then remove everything before it

Tags: jquery, regex

I have an issue with RegEx I'm trying to figure out.

For instance I have a url

```
http://localhost:8888/faqs/#answer290
```

What I want to do is check the url to see if the URL contains a hash and if it does then remove everything before it so I'm left with just

```
#answer290
```

What I have so far is

```
$("div#questions ul li a").click(function(e){
    var selected = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(selected);
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
        var location = window.location,
            result = /\/([^\/]*)$/.exec(location)[1];
        selected = result;
        console.log(result);
        alert("your url contains #");
    } else {
        selected = selected
    }
    $('.top-button').remove();
    $('.current-faq').removeClass();
    $.scrollTo(selected, 400);
    $(selected).append('<a href="#" class="top-button">TOP</a>');
    $(selected).addClass('current-faq');
});
```

To explain more of what I am doing is on the FAQs page it will find the corresponding section with the hash and scroll there, but the issue is when I come from another page the url for **selected** is different than when it's on the actual FAQ page.

On the FAQ page the alert fires, but for some reason when I come another page that links the questions it doesn't fire.

I'm trying to strip the whole url from another page so it has just everything after the hash.

I seem to be close but having difficulty getting the last part

Thanks

Comment: So you want `location.hash`?

Comment: @JonathanSampson it looks like it's coming from href attribute of a link

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Looks like the OP is going to `window.location` after a n anchor click event. `window.location.href.indexOf("#")`.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: The href attribute of a link shares the properties of the location object, so you can access `.hash` on it as well.

Comment: @CBroe yup, I did it in my answer.

Comment: Correct, the events apply correctly if on the actual page but when coming from another page that links to the FAQ page it doesn't work.  Even still after applying any of these examples it returns the correct information but the styling isn't being applied like it should be when coming from another page.  I figured since the url is different coming from another page, if i stripped it and just sent the the stripped part it would work but so far no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need RegEx for that. indexOf/substring will do:

```
var s = "http://localhost:8888/faqs/#answer290";

var i = s.indexOf("#")

if (i != -1) {
    alert(s.substring(i, s.length));
}
```

If you need to read a hash property of an anchor, you can use `.prop('hash')`. e.g. for

```
<a id="link" href="http://localhost:8888/faqs/#answer290">link</a>
```

`$("#link").prop("hash")` will get "#answer290"

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
  var index = window.location.indexOf("#");
  var location = window.location;
  if(index != -1) {
     location = location.substring(index, location.length);
  }
```